# Order by attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a WooCommerce based website and trying to figure out how to order my products by their **attribute value**. I looked on the internet and can not seem to find any solutions. My attributes have values based on numbers and I want to be able to sort those low to high. Hope this makes any sense.

Thanks alot for reading this and have a nice day,

Sjoerd